# Doxygen: how to reference java generic interface in documentation

Tags: java, doxygen

I have some Java interface with doxygen documentation

```
public interface Service< T , U > {
    ...
}
```

Doxygen is creating docu for class `Service< T, U >`. When I'm trying to reference this docu page from some other page with @ref tag `@ref Service< T , U>`, warning is generated:

```
warning: unable to resolve reference to 'Service' for \ref command
```

It looks like @ref is not friendly with "<" in the name.

Does anyone know some workaround to reference class with "<" sing in the name?

Comment: Did you try @ref Service?

Comment: Yes, sure. Result is the same - warning. And it is clear why - docu is created for Service<T,U>, so I should reference to it somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem with the following example:

```
/** A service */
public interface Service< T , U > {
}


/** @mainpage
 *  See @ref Service<T,U> "the service interface" for details.
 */
```

but it worked fine (as I would expect).

Comment: Problem solved after moving from doxygen version 1.7.6.1 to 1.8.4. Thank you for help